# UTF8Encoding doesn't throw exception on an incomplete character at the end

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding

I noticed that the `UTF8Encoding` class does not throw an exception if the input byte sequence ends with an incomplete character, and the input is read using `StreamReader`. For example, the following program outputs `0` and doesn't throw an exception. If the byte sequence continued, an exception would be thrown. If there were valid characters in the beginning, they would be included in the output. What is the correct way to read an UTF8 byte stream such that an exception is thrown on incomplete characters?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public class Test {
static void utf8Test() {
    byte[] bbuf = new byte[] { 228 };
    string t;
    using (var s = new MemoryStream(bbuf)) {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(s,new UTF8Encoding(true,true))) {
            t = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(t.Length);
}

public static void Main() {
    utf8Test();
}
}
```

**Edit:**
The following method does throw an exception, because the `flush` argument is `true`:

```
    static void convertTest() {
      byte[] bbuf = new byte[] { 65, 228 };
      char[] cbuf = new char[100];
      var dec = new UTF8Encoding(true,true).GetDecoder();
      int bytesUsed, charsUsed;
      bool completed;
      bool flush = true;
      dec.Convert(bbuf,0,bbuf.Length,cbuf,0,cbuf.Length, flush, out bytesUsed, out charsUsed, out completed);
      Console.WriteLine(charsUsed);
    }
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.decoderreplacementfallback(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That doesn't help because `StreamReader` doesn't signal the decoder that the input is finished, so the decoder does not get the chance to throw an exception. It is probably a bug in `StreamReader`.

Comment: It does.  Works just fine when I try it, nice kaboom.